# Jenkins - Pentaho executar script como usuário logado

Tags: jenkins, pentaho

Boa tarde senhores,

Estou utilizando o Jenkins, para executar um job no Pentaho,  esse job executa um script, que simula a interação do usuário, porém como o Jenkins executa em segundo plano, ele não associa a nenhum usuário, e com isso o script não funciona, existe alguma possibilidade,  de executar setando o usuário do Windows?

Answer (score -2):

Opa!
Você pode instalar o [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), para inserir o usuário e senha e executar o script através do seguinte comando:

```
  psexec \\computername -u domain\user -p password
```

Você pode colocar para ser executado no Job do Jenkins.
[image: execute-bat-jenkins]

Um exemplo de abrir uma página http através do PsExec:

```
psexec \\computername -u domain\user -p password "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" https://www.google.com
```